# Right click (Context Click) not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have made a number of tests that I run via selenium. However I'm having problem with right click on an element. I get an exception saying that *an element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters*.

This is strange because just before I right click on it I select the element using a `click event`. I'm unsure why I get the exception when I'm trying to right click on an element I'm able to select.

My code is as follows:

```
var e= webDriverWait
  .Until(ExpectedConditions
    .ElementTo‌​BeClickable(session.FindElementByName(elementName))
  );

webDriverWait
  .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(e))
  .Click();

Actions action = new Actions(session).ContextClick(e);
action
  .Build()
  .Perform();
```